# Update persisted List<Entity> with Java persistence

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, ebean

I have a `List` with a `@OneToMany` annotation as an Entity variable in Java. The problem is, that if I add new `RequestPeople` or `RequestProject` into the Lists and then execute `foo.update()` to update an existing `Request` stored in the DB, Java tries to create new rows and fails due to `UNIQUE_KEY` constraints in the REQUESTS_PEOPLE and REQUESTS_PROJECTS tables.
Here are the Classes:

**Parent Entity - Request**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REQUESTS")
public class Request extends Model
{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name = "id")
   private long id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "request", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   private List<RequestPeople> peopleList;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "request", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   private List<RequestProject> projectsList;

   // constructors, getters, setters
}
```

**Child - RequestPeople**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REQUESTS_PEOPLE",
       uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"request_id", "person_id"}))
public class RequestPeople extends Model
{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private long id;

   @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Request.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "request_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
   private Request request;

   @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Person.class)
   @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
   private Person person;

   // constructors, getters, setters
}
```

**Child - RequestProject**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REQUESTS_PROJECTS",
       uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"request_id", "project_id"}))
public class RequestProject extends Model
{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private long id;

   @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Request.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "request_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
   private Request request;

   @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Project.class)
   @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
   private Project project;

   // constructors, getters, setters
}
```

Third Entities (Person and Project) are just simple Entities. Here are the IDs of these:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;
```

The above Entities create 3 tables in the DB (MySQL). At some point I create a `new ArrayList<RequestPeople>()` and a `new ArrayList<RequestProject>()` and I populate these with Entities. When I add these Lists into `tempRequest` which is type of `Request.class` and execute `tempRequest.save()`, Java stores the `tempRequest` into `REQUESTS` table, and for the Lists it creates multiple entries in the other tables. **This works fine**

The problem is when I try to add new people in the `peopleList` (or projects). If I get back from the DB the previous entity, add the new people in the List and I execute `tempRequest.update()`, it throws a `PersistenceException` showing that it violates `UNIQUE_KEY` constraint in the child tables.

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: ERROR executing DML bindLog[] error[Duplicate entry '1-30' for key 'uq_acccess_requests_people_1']
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.DmlBeanPersister.execute(DmlBeanPersister.java:90)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.dml.DmlBeanPersister.insert(DmlBeanPersister.java:57)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersistExecute.executeInsertBean(DefaultPersistExecute.java:59)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.PersistRequestBean.executeNow(PersistRequestBean.java:451)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.PersistRequestBean.executeOrQueue(PersistRequestBean.java:485)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.insert(DefaultPersister.java:261)
.
.
.
```

Any idea how to resolve this error??

**PS** We are using Ebean ORM to persist the Objects

---

#### Edit

Here is how I retrieve the entry from the DB:

```
Request tempRequest = Ebean.find(Request.class).where().eq("id", id).findUnique();
```

Comment: Programmers like List<>, but in such JPA situation Set<> has many advantages (i.e. has naturally unique data, better speed)

Comment: if you dont mind please let me see the service implementation .  I think you are not taking the exact object from db via repository.

Comment: @VishnuKR I added the command to retrieve the object from the DB. I'm not sure what you mean by "service implementation"

Comment: @JacekCz Thanks for the advice. To be honest this is the first time I try to persist a Collection and I found many example over the web referring to a java.util.List. I'll keep that in mind

Comment: If `RequestProject.request` is of type `AccessRequest`, why would you declare `Request.projectsList` in `Request` as being the inverse side of the association? Either declare `projectsList ` in `AccessRequest` or change the type of `RequestProject.request` to `Request`

Comment: @crizzis good point but this is just a typo in my sample code. I changed the class names in the post from original code to be more readable in SO. I edited the question above. `RequestProject.request` was always of the correct type (i.e type of `Request`)